# What WCF extensibility point should I use to implement custom security?

Tags: wcf, security, .net-4.0

I'm trying to create a flexible security infrastructure for our WCF services on our intranet, but I'm not quite sure where I should be putting this code... there are so many different ways to extend WCF that I don't know for sure where to begin...

The basic idea: every time my service is called - for any operation - I want some code to run that does a custom access check using our existing security infrastructure to see if the user has access to perform the operation. If the user isn't authorized, I want it to throw an exception or something (not sure what it should do really) and prevent the call from ever making it to my service code.

Thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to use a MessageInspector in conjunction with a ParameterInspector to make it work how I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731181.aspx) will be a good starting point for implementing a custom authorization strategy.